# getParameter returns null

Tags: jsp, servlets

Excuse me for the silly questions in advance, but this shot snippet doesn't work properly. The JSP prints out "null" Find the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="ServletController" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="invoice">
            <input type="text" name="amount">
            <input type="text" name="date">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
public class ServletController extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        String invoice = req.getParameter("invoice");
        String amount = req.getParameter("amount");
        String date = req.getParameter("date");
        //connection = new DBConn();
        //connection.createConnection(invoice, amount, date);
        req.setAttribute("attr", invoice);
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%-- String str = (String) request.getParameter("invoice");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.print(str);
    --%>
  ${param.invoice}
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServContr</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>classes.ServletController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServContr</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</servlet>
```

If I put scriplet code JSP returns "null", in EL case JSP nothing. I tried to experiment with HTML-form, becasuse I think the problem that browser doesn't make request properly, but nothing. PLease give me an idea where the mistake is and why ${} doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Tiny, thank you for edditing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My browser does this implicitly, maybe yours doesn't.

Add an `enctype` to your `form`

```
<form action="ServletController" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

so that the browser serializes the form elements into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content that you can retrieve with `HttpServletRequest#getParameter(String)`.

Comment: Sotirios, thanks a lot! It works! The previous version of Chrome made it right without enctype-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Sotirios Delimanolis, Most of the cases are covers under his solution, in addition to that please check for multiple parameters to be formed in request URL

```
<input type="hidden" name="regId" id="regId" />
```

and the submit Function be like

```
function fnSubmit()
{
 document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled=true;
 document.forms[0].action="someURL&regId=2";
 document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

This will create two values of the regId, and server will assume it as an array, request.getParameter will return null, and request.getParameterValues will return a String Array.